# Imageview doesn't work when I insert code into mainactivity

Tags: android

I put my image, picture1.png, in the drawable folder in the res directory.

In the activity_main.xml I put the code

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myimageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/picture1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
```

My image successfully loads when I run the app.

However, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_resources.htm says that I have to set an imageview using a imageview code (below). Presumably, I can use this in a dynamic way perhaps with an 'if' function so the image isn't just there all the time.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
```

I modified the

```
myimage
```

to

```
picture1
```

and this is my mainactivity code:

```
package com.example.alby.testapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture1);



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

However, the app fails to load and is terminated.

```
error: <identifier> expected
error: <identifier> expected

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Why is this the case? By the way, if I only put the

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);
```

below the @Override portion of the next, there is no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have code outside of any method.

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture1);
```

---

You cannot use `findViewById` outside any method anyway, so try this instead.

```
ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture1);
}
```

> says that I have to set an imageview using a imageview code

No, it did not say you **have to**.

`android:src="@drawable/..."` is the XML way of saying `.setImageResource(R.drawable...)`, so use one or the other.

Comment: Thanks that worked out. However, you said that I did not have a method so I tried creating a method, i put ImageView imageView; then  public void main(String [] arg) { the two imageView lines inside here} but it didn't work. The app loaded fine, but the image didn't come up. Why does it work in the onCreate method but not in the main function? @cricket_007

Comment: Sorry I probably should take a break and then come back to this...thanks for your help

Comment: In other words, for any Java program `main` is **similar** to `onCreate`... (read any hello world android app, and that is the only method), however, as stated, Android is not like "pure Java"

Comment: Ahh...I see this is starting to make sense now. ..so thats what "If you have worked with C, C++ or Java programming language then you must have seen that your program starts from main() function. Very similar way, Android system initiates its program with in an Activity starting with a call on onCreate() callback method." means. I see, thanks very much!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you figured it out. Happy coding!